# React Native Debugger not logging Android emulator network calls on Windows 10

Tags: windows, react-native, debugging, networking

I switched to Windows 10 for a bit and I cannot figure out why my Android emulator is not logging my API calls via React Native Debugger under the network tab

Currently the only calls under the network tab being logged are from `http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/...`

Is there a setting that I am missing on android studio?

more info:
App created w/ Expo
Windows 10 Home
Android Studio 4.2.1

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, did you ever found a solution for this?